# What is the next permutation after $564321$?

Tags: algorithms, permutations

**Background and Question**

My Rosen's Discrete Mathematics textbook gives a great and easy-to-follow algorithm for finding the next largest permutation given a certain permutation, and there's also a great algorithm on wikipedia (essentially the same one) that is discussed [in this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string).

The question I have is taken from a different book that I must use for my online Discrete Math course. It asks that I find the next permutation that is greater than $564321$.

**Approach**

Well, using the algorithm, I came up with the solution of $651234$.

You first find the last pair of digits for which the first ($a_j$) is smaller than the second ($a_{j+1}$). This is the pair $56$ (because $5$ < $6$). Next, you examine the remaining digits $a_i$ for $i \in [j+1, n]$ and find the least of them that happens to be greater than the digit in the $j$th position ($a_j = 5$). In our situation, the only integer that satisfies this criteron is $6$. Now we swap them and get: $654321$.

But then the algorithm says that for all elements after $i$ (which in this case is the former position of the $6$, currently occupied by the $5$), we reverse the order: $651234$.

**Question**

Is my textbook's solution wrong? They are saying the answer should be $612345$. But that's not what the algorithm produces.

Comment: Why is it not $612345$?

Comment: Actually, I apologize, the book said $612345$. I wrote the wrong answer earlier. Still wondering why that's the correct answer, though.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see my mistake. You're correct, and so is the book. $5$ was among the elements that I had to sort.

Comment: No problem, and would just like to point out that this can usually be done by inspection (with practice) which can help you double check your answer from the algorithm in future.

Comment: I don't think I'm familiar with inspection. Is it a specific method, or do you mean just inspecting my work? Thanks!

Comment: Inspection means 'at a glance', basically. It's hard to explain, but if I have to list permutations for something or other, I've gotten into the habit of listing them in order, and that way I can make sure I won't miss one.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Thanks again; makes sense :)

Comment: I will point out that the phrase "*the* **next** *permutation*" is quite ambiguous since you have not specified with respect to what order.  The permutation which follows $564321$ is $612345$ with respect to [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), but this is of course not the only way to order permutations (*or strings in general*).  For example, in colexicographic ordering, the "next" permutation after $564321$ is $645321$ followed again by $465321$.